# Dúvida Aninhamento de Structs

Tags: c, struct

Preciso fazer um programa que cadastre produto e inclua esses produtos em um carrinho de venda e finalize a venda.

Antes eu já tinha feito um programa que cadastrava os produtos, que continha somente a struct Produto:

Assim:

```
struct Produto{
    int codigo;
    char descricao[51];
    float valor;
} vprodutos[10];

void incluir();
void excluir(int codigo);
void listar();
void alterar(int coidgo);
void buscar(int codigo);

int posicao;

void incluir(){
    system("cls");

    if(posicao < 10){
        printf("Digite o codigo do produto: \n");
        scanf("%d", &vprodutos[posicao].codigo);
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("Digite a descricao do produto: \n");
        gets(vprodutos[posicao].descricao);
        printf("Digite o valor do produto: \n");
        scanf("%f", &vprodutos[posicao].valor);
        printf("Cadastro efetuado com sucesso!!!\n");
        posicao++;
    }else{
        printf("Memoria cheia!!!\n");
        }
    system("pause");
}
```

---

Agora tenho 2 structs fiz assim e está apresentando erro: 
error: 'struct Produto' has no member named 'estoque' - Produto não tem nenhum membro nomeado estoque:

```
struct Produto{
    int codigo;
    char descricao[51];
    float valor;
}vprodutos[10];

struct Carrinho{
    int item;
    struct Produto estoque;
    int qtd;
    float subtotal;
}vcarrinho[100];

void menu_manutencao();
void abrircompra(int codigo);
//void fecharCompra();
void incluir();
//void excluir(int codigo);
void listar();
//void alterar(int coidgo);
//void buscar(int codigo);

int posicao;
int posicaovenda;

void incluir(){
    system("cls");

if(posicaovenda < 10){

        printf("Digite o codigo do produto: \n");
        scanf("%d", &vprodutos[posicaovenda].estoque.codigo);
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("Digite a descricao do produto: \n");
        gets(vprodutos[posicaovenda].estoque.descricao);
        printf("Digite o valor do produto: \n");
        scanf("%f", &vprodutos[posicaovenda].estoque.codigo);
        printf("Cadastro efetuado com sucesso!!!\n");
        posicao++;
    }else{
        printf("Memoria cheia!!!\n");
        }
    system("pause");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Acho que o certo seria utilizar `&vcarrinho[posicaovenda].estoque.codigo`, pois o struct Carrinho que possui o struct Produto.

Talvez ocorra algum erro por criar vetores com tamanhos diferentes.

Também parece que a variável `posicaovenda` não está sendo incrementada...